# Drop down list - input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have below metod:

```
private void BindModels(int makeID, int typeID)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["ds_DDLsData"];
        EnumerableRowCollection models;
        if (typeID != null)
        {
            models = from dt_Models in ds.Tables[10].AsEnumerable()
                         where dt_Models.Field<int>("MakeID") == makeID & dt_Models.Field<int>("TypeID") == typeID
                         select new
                         {
                             modelName = dt_Models.Field<string>("ModelName"),
                             modelID = dt_Models.Field<int>("ModelID")
                         };
        }
        else
        {
            models = from dt_Models in ds.Tables[10].AsEnumerable()
                     where dt_Models.Field<int>("MakeID") == makeID
                     select new
                     {
                         modelName = dt_Models.Field<string>("ModelName"),
                         modelID = dt_Models.Field<int>("ModelID")
                     };
        }

        ddlModel.DataSource = models;
        ddlModel.DataTextField = "ModelName";
        ddlModel.DataValueField = "ModelID";
        ddlModel.DataBind();
        ddlModel.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select Model --", "-1"));
        ddlModel.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex.Message.ToString());
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
        methods.LogErrors(Session["user"].ToString(), this.Page.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString(), ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

which I call from:

```
    protected void ddlMake_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (pnlModels.Visible == false)
        {
            pnlModels.Visible = true;
        }

        BindModels(Convert.ToInt32(ddlMake.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex.Message.ToString());
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
        methods.LogErrors(Session["user"].ToString(), this.Page.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString(), ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The problem is that in some cases Type drop down list can be empty. My question is how BindModels method should look like, because now I am receiving error - Input string was not in a correct format. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Why do you try to convert an empty string to an `int` at all? What's so difficult in  checking `ddlType.SelectedValue` before you call `BindModels`?

Comment: Tim - ok I got what you mean. Could you please tell me how I can handle this?

Comment: Just check it with: `if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlType.SelectedValue)){BindModels(...);}`

Comment: Ok, but will it populate Models without Type condition?

Comment: No, but you havent mentioned that before. Apart from that your code does not compile. `int typeID` and `if (typeID != null)`. A value type like int cannot be null. Do you actually use an `int?`? Then you can pass null for tghe type to `BindModels`.